# Nearest $a$ to $b$ s.t. $\text{gcd}(a,b)=c$ ( without trial and error)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Been playing with properties of $\text{gcd}$ , in specific pondered what numbers satisfy $\text{gcd}(100,a)=4$, it seems all the numbers $a=4k$ where k is odd should satisfy $\text{gcd}(100,a)=4$.
With trial and error it is possible to find the closest $a$ s.t. $\text{gcd}(100,a)=4$

my question is, is there a computational way to find the Nearest $a$ to $b$ s.t. $\text{gcd}(a,b)=c$ , where $b,c$ are given. ( without trial and error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check whether $c$ is a divisor of $b$.  If not, it's not possible.  If so, then $a = b\pm c$ are the closest values to $b$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=c$.

As for your particular case, note that $\gcd(4k,100)=4$ is true if and only if $k$ isn't divisible by $5$.  It has nothing to do with $k$ being odd.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously we have $c\mid b$.

Then you can simply set $a$ to be one multiple of $c$ less than $b$.  In other words, $$a=b-c.$$

Comment: This is not correct.  For the given example, $b=100,c=4$ it gives $a=24$, but it should be $96$

Comment: You're right, we'd have to multiply by the divisor again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $b$ is a multiple of $c$ (if not, there is no solution) it is just $a=b-c$ or $a=b+c$